# Path string format '/' to '\'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, string-formatting

i have a problem about string format.

first, i have table on the database and the record is

```
id | url
---|-----------------
1  | \root\folder\file.txt
```

and i have to access query like this one,

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE url like @param;
```

then, on the server-side. i have code

```
String path = "/folder/file.txt";
```

my problem is, how to change "/folder/file.txt" to "\folder\file.txt"?

if i use

```
path = path.Replace('/','\\'); or path = path.Replace("/",@"\");
```

i get path is "\\folder\\file.txt"

if i assign @param with path
`DataSource.SelectParameters["param"].DefaultValue = "%"+path`

my query is not correct. there is other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's `.Replace` not `.replace` by the way. C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape `\`, so what you've already tried works

```
path = path.Replace('/', '\\');
```

What you see is just the debugger, click on the loupe and you'll see that it's actually the desired: `\folder\file.txt` and not `\\folder\\file.txt`.

According to your second question which starts with *"if i assign @param with path"* i cannot help since i've never used declarative datasource controls  in ASP.NET.